# Why does text-shadow offset clip-path?

Tags: html, css, clipping

I was tearing my hair out for hours over why my `clip-path` values seemed to be getting offset until I finally figured out the culprit: `text-shadow`'s blur value.

The following code snippet should explain it pretty well:

```css
.glow {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #00e;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #e00;
}

.clipped {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    /* +2 to clip point positions to account for 1px border */
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 42px, 402px 42px, 402px 0px, 0px 0px);
    clip-path: url("#clipPath");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="clipped">
        <span class="glow">glowing text</span> and not glowing text
        <br />
        more not glowing text
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="clipped">
        no glowing text at all here
        <br />
        but otherwise the same as the first div
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="clipPath">
        <polygon points="0 42,402 42,402 0,0 0">
        </polygon>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Why is a `text-shadow` interfering with the behavior of the clipping path at all? Is there any way to get around it? Are there any other bizarre differences that `text-shadow` makes that I should know about?

Comment: _Why is this happening?_ - Why is what happening? Please be more specific.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Edited to make the question clearer.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but increasing the co-ordinates seems to solve the issue. ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my2Le6ob/).

Comment: @chipChocolate.py No, it only masks the problem. Tryt increasing the blur value and the problem re-appears

Comment: @vals The values have to be incremented by the same amount as the blur value. That's what I'd probably go with if there's no way to get around the problem, but it's not much more than a band-aid solution.

Comment: yes, it's kind of a hack. No idea about why this is happening, anyway

Comment: @Hydrothermal - Try using `svg`'s `clipPath` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Nope! It doesn't solve the problem. ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my2Le6ob/1/)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I've updated the question with SVG clipping; it doesn't change anything in Chrome, but it seems to work perfectly in Firefox.

Comment: @Hydrothermal - Firefox doesn't support CSS `clip-path`. Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my2Le6ob/1/)(in Firefox/Chrome) that I posted 2 minutes ago. It uses `svg` `clipPath`.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It does if you use an `<svg>` path - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04r3q9wy/). Changing the values on line 19 and re-running should update the clipping (on 34.0.5, at least).

Comment: @Hydrothermal - Well, yes that seems to work. But still won't work on Chrome.